# If we denote $X$ to be the set of primes $p$ such that $N_p(f)>1$ for polynomial $f(x)$, is it true that $X$ has positive relative density?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be an irreducible polynomial and $N_p(f)$ be the number of solutions of congruence $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ for some prime $p$.

Then if we denote $X$ to be the set of primes $p$ such that $N_p(f)>1$, is it true that $X$ has positive relative density in the set of primes?

Comment: Yes this is a simple application of the Chebotarev density theorem.

Comment: @Daniel Loughran can you possibly give some reference or a sketch of it.Thanks

Comment: Any prime which splits completely in the extension generated by the roots of f has the property that $N_p(f)=deg(f)$ if the left hand side counts multiplicity of zeroes. For sufficiently large p there won’t be any repeated roots.